# performance issue when joining two large tables

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, optimization

I have a multilingual CMS that uses a translation table (70k rows) that contains all of the texts

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `translations` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `key` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `lang` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `value` text CHARACTER SET utf8,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    KEY `key` (`key`,`lang`)
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM
```

and products table (4k rows) containing products with translation keys

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `products` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name_trans_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `desc_trans_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `text_trans_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `name_index` (`name_trans_id`),
  KEY `desc_index` (`desc_trans_id`),
  KEY `text_index` (`text_trans_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM
```

now i need to get top 20 products in alphabetical order, to do that i use this query :

```
SELECT 
    SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  
    dt_table.* , 
    t_name.value as 'name'  
FROM  
    products as dt_table  
    LEFT JOIN 
    `translations` as t_name on dt_table.name_trans_id = t_name.key  
WHERE  
    (t_name.lang = 1 OR t_name.lang is null)  
ORDER BY 
    name ASC LIMIT 0, 20
```

It takes forever.
Any help optimizing this query/tables will be appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your structure of `translations` table to:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `translations` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `key` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `lang` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    `value` text CHARACTER SET utf8,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    KEY `lang` (`lang`),
    KEY `key` (`key`,`lang`),
    FULLTEXT idx (`value`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

because you really need `lang` to be indexed as soon as you use it in `WHERE` clause.

And try to change your query a little bit:

```
SELECT 
    dt_table.* , 
    t_name.value as 'name',
    SUBSTR(t_name.value,0,100) as text_order
FROM  
    products as dt_table  
    LEFT JOIN ( 
       SELECT key, value FROM `translations` 
       WHERE  lang = 1 OR lang is null
) as t_name
ON dt_table.name_trans_id = t_name.key  
ORDER BY 
    text_order ASC LIMIT 0, 20
```

and if you really need `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` (I don't understand why do you need counter for translations items)
you can run another query just right after the first one:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM products;
```

I am pretty sure you will be surprised with performance :-)

Comment: thank for your answer, but unfortunately it does not help. the problem is 'order by' clause. this query with some added 'where' params take 55 seconds, and only 1.4 seconds when no ordering is applied

Comment: do you really need order by TEXT field?

Comment: yes, i need to provide filtering and ordering option to the user, order something alphabetical order is a basic request

Comment: but you can change type to `VARCHAR` in most cases

Comment: my longest row contains 23K bytes of text, i tried converting them to varchar(10k) and then execution time increased 5! times. i found the answer to that here : http://nicj.net/mysql-text-vs-varchar-performance/

Comment: sure, but order by value of 23K ?? that has no sense at all

Comment: the translation table is used to things like product description as well

Comment: check my updated answer, add `FULLTEXT idx (\`value\`)` fulltext index to the table and change engine `ENGINE=InnoDB;`

Comment: The `lang IS NULL` applies to the LEFT JOIN, and cannot be rearranged as you suggest.

Comment: thank you for your help, with some tinkering i managed to get down to 2+ seconds, so i can live with it for now